# Which command is used to remove newline characters from strings

Tags: python

I am trying to remove newline characters from the variable `q`.

I am new to python and trying to do this way but this is not working:

```
q.strip()
```

Comment: "``but this is not working``" - please provide a [mcve], including the desired output vs the actual output

Comment: `strip` will remove newlines at the beginning and end of a string, but not the middle. Your example should show _what_ didn't work (perhaps assign something to `q`) so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

[`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) removes whitespace (including newlines) at the *very beginning* and *very end* of the string. It doesn't remove them in the middle of the string (i.e., if there between any non-whitespace characters, they won't get removed).

You can instead use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) to replace them all with nothing (remove them).

```py
q = q.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working… it’s a general question like if the variable is q then which command will be used to remove newline characters from the variables… if you can please help

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without know what your string contains. Can you post what your string is **in your question**?

Comment: @Hassan - just post a full working example of the problem. This will remove all carriage returns and line feeds. Somehow its not working for you... so show us!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use `.splitlines` and then `.join` the list together:

```
string = "hello\nworld\n"
new_string = " ".join(string.splitlines()) # Splitlines returns a list so we need to join it together using .join
print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
hello
world

hello world
```